# Can't start mining on TEST-NET in Ethereum Wallet

Tags: go-ethereum, mining, testnets

Just installed Ethereum Wallet, downloaded blockchain, but can't start mining on TEST-NET. When I click 'Start mining', I get console error. Also I can't start mining from console. See screenshots attachted. How can I start mining?

[image: pic1]
[image: pic2]

Comment: You are waiting when the sync is finished for mining?

Comment: I want to see that mining has started.

Comment: Yes, but in the first image you don't are sync with the testnet.

Comment: Syncin never finished...

Comment: So first you need to solve this, before try to mine nothing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, for me solution was not to use Etherium Wallet but use [mist](https://github.com/ethereum/mist/releases) instead. Very important to use 64bit version, because 32bit version crashes with outOfMemory almost with 100% guaranty, while desktop interface wouldn't give any sign of this crash. Also, even if everything goes ok, before you launch the application, after blocks have been downloaded, you should wait till they are verified (or arranged). As soon as you see no 100% CPU and HDD/IO activity, kill application, restart it and only after that mining will work.